# A quantity computed from weights of representations -- Have you seen it?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

The following quantity has come up in some work my collaborators and I are doing on equivariant D-modules, and in that particular context it seems to be very significant (i.e. it's the only "interesting" parameter in a certain naturally-defined family of D-modules). Has this quantity come up before?

Here are the details:

Let $G$ be a semisimple complex algebraic group, $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra, $\mathfrak{h}$ a Cartan subalgebra. Fix a choice of positive roots, and let $\rho$ be the Weyl vector (i.e. the half-sum of the positive roots). Let $W$ be an irreducible $G$-representation with highest weight $\mu$. The quantity in question is
$$\frac{2\langle \rho, \mu\rangle}{\langle\mu,\mu\rangle},$$
where $\langle-,-\rangle$ is the bilinear form on $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathfrak{h},\mathbb{C})$ dual to (the restriction to $\mathfrak{h}$ of) the Killing form.

In our particular case, $W$ is $H^0(X,\mathcal{L})$, where $X$ is a projective homogeneous space for $G$, and $\mathcal{L}$ is a very ample $G$-equivariant line bundle on $X$.

Comment: In the usual root system notation (following e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#Definition), where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the Killing form, the quantity you are talking about would usually be denoted $\langle \rho, \mu \rangle$. Unless I'm confusing something...

Comment: It is related to Hilbert polynomial for the dimensions $H^0(X,\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n})$ as a polynomial in $n$.  The top degree term in the polynomial is a homogeneous polynomial in $n$.  If you divide through by this homogeneous polynomial, you get something like $1-(2\langle \rho,\mu\rangle/\langle \mu,\mu \rangle) (\text{dim}(X)/n)$ plus lower order terms.  This follows from the Koll'ar -- Matsusaka version of "asymptotic Riemann-Roch".

Comment: @SamHopkins  That is true, but usually those terms are only defined if the input weights are roots (they certainly *could* be defined for other weights, but they usually only come up for roots).

Comment: @jasonstarr morally, the Hilbert polynomial thing is where this quantity came from

Comment: Those two terms in the Hilbert polynomial (the highest degree term together with the next highest degree term) also arise in several invariants considered in algebraic geometry: the "alpha invariant" and the Futaki invariant, for instance.

Comment: @JasonStarr Do you mean the paper "Riemann-Roch type inequalities" by Koll'ar and Matsutaka? From taking a quick glance at the paper, it seems to only be giving inequalities about the dimensions of $H^0(X, \mathcal{L}^{\otimes n})$, hence not the Hilbert polynomial. Can you point me to which part of the paper you were referring to?